# How can I filter a list of paths from a bunch of text?

Tags: shell-script, grep, zsh

I have a text file (.txt) that has several paths and I want to filter them and leave only a list of paths.

The file would be something like this:

```
Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadip"/one/path/I_want_to_keep"iscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua
Utenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercitationul"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"lamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat
Duisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitess"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"ecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariatur
Excepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproident"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum
```

The paths as shown in the example have 3 slashes (/), are surrounded by quotes (""), the last part of the path are several words separated by underscores (_), and the text around doesn’t have a specific pattern.

I am using zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this:

```bsh
% grep -o '"/[^"]*"' file
"/one/path/I_want_to_keep"
"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"
"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"
"/another/path/I_want_to_keep"
```

Comment: beware that on a `"foo"/"bar"` input, it finds `"/"`

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print for grep m{^/.*/.*/}, /"(.*?)"/g' < your-file
```

Would extract the contents of quoted strings (assuming they don't span several lines) and grep the ones that start with `/` and contain at least two extra `/`s`.

On an input like

```
"foo"/x/y/"bar"/"/a/b/c"/"/X/Y"
```

That's `foo`, `bar`, `/a/b/c` and `/X/Y` strings, only the third of which matches the `grep()` criteria so we only get `/a/b/c` as output. See how `"/x/y/"` is also not reported as that `/x/y/` is actually outside of quotes.

Since you mention `zsh`, to do something similar with `zsh` operators, you'd do:

```
set -o extendedglob
string='"foo"/x/y/"bar"/"/a/b/c"/"/X/Y"'

quoted_strings=()
: ${(S)string//(#b)\"(*)\"/${quoted_strings[$#quoted_strings+1]::=$match[1]}}

print -rC1 ${(M)quoted_strings:#/*/*/*}
```

Where

- the `S` parameter expansion flag turns on non-greedy matching for the `${param//pattern/replacement}` matching.
- `(#b)` (for which we need `extendedglob`) enables `b`ack-references (for what is matched by `(*)` to be available in `$match[1]`)
- `${var::=value}` unconditionally assigns `value` to `$var` upon expansion (a variation on the `${var-value}` / `${var:-value}` of the Bourne shell). We use it here to append the matches to the `$quoted_strings` array.
- `print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `${(M)array:#pattern}` expands to the elements of the `array` that `M`atch the `pattern` (`${var:#pattern}` being a variation on ksh's `${var#pattern}`/`${var%pattern}` which removes the whole element as a whole instead of just a prefix / suffix, and the `M` parameter expansion flag reverts it (keeps the matches instead of removing them).